# The doctrine:generate:entities command has been deprecated

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

NOTE: The doctrine:generate:entities command has been deprecated.
       To read more about the differences between anemic and rich models go her
 http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/get
ing-started.html#adding-behavior-to-entities.
       If you wish to generate your entities, use make:entity --regenerate from
MakerBundle instead.

Comment: What did you do to get the exception? Please elaborate more in your question

Comment: when I made the generation of entities he gave me this error                                        
                                                                                                                    NOTE: The doctrine:generate:entities command has been deprecated. To read more about the differences between anemic and rich models go her http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/get ing-started.html#adding-behavior-to-entities. If you wish to generate your entities, use make:entity --regenerate from MakerBundle instead.

Comment: You should try `php bin/console make:entity --regenerate` it is literally in the error message.

Comment: This is not a question, and you got an URL that will explain you things... Have you gone and read it?

Comment: this url it does not work sir

Comment: You are using Symfony 4+, in this version sensio has been added MakeBundle to make easier the make tasks, make an entity, controller, command, voter, etc. You can read about this awesome bundle here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html

Comment: What Symfony version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this message in a Symfony 3.4 project.

The message is recommending that you use the Symfony Maker Bundle's `make:entity` command instead of `doctrine:generate:entities`.

Symfony Maker Bundle is compatible with Symfony 3.4, but not included.

Solution #1: ignore the message and continue using `doctrine:generate:entities` since it's only generating code and that code won't stop working if you upgrade Symfony later and `doctrine:generate:entities` is removed.

Solution #2: install Symfony Maker Bundle and use the suggested replacement command: `composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev`. ( I had to update `doctrine/inflector` as well)

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html

I would personally go with Solution #1 if you are indeed using Symfony 3.4. The maker bundle seems quite fussy about the location and structure if your entities and repositories and there are still a few bugs by the look of it.

The part about 'differences between anemic and rich models' appears to be a warning about the make command overwriting your getters and setters. If you have custom code in those you may loose it.